# Error PS1 git functions - conflict between Gitbash vs Cygwin

Tags: bash, cygwin, git-bash, ps1

I'm receiving the following error trying to customize my PS1 for git

## Error:

```bash
bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
bash: command substitution: line 1: `get_dir)'
bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
bash: command substitution: line 1: `get_branch)'
bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
bash: command substitution: line 1: `parse_git_dirty)'
```

### My .bashrc

```bash
#...
function get_dir() {
    [[ ${PWD} == $HOME ]] && echo '~' || echo ${PWD##*/}
}
function get_branch() {
    [[ -d .git ]] && echo "$(git branch --show-current)" 
}
#...
```

Here's tricky! this first snipped worked perfectly on my Cygwin, but produce that error on Gitbash

```bash
export PS1="${LIGHTGREEN}\t${NC} ${PINK}\$(get_dir)${NC}${LIGHTBLUE} \$(get_branch) ${NC}${RED}\$(parse_git_dirty)${NC} \n${GREEN}$ ${NC}"
```

when I "fix it" using this syntax, I've got no error but it's NOT working dynamically. I Need to reload my .bashrc each time that I change the directory

```bash
export PS1="${LIGHTGREEN}\t${NC} ${PINK}`get_dir`${NC}${LIGHTBLUE} `get_branch` ${NC}${RED}`parse_git_dirty`${NC} \n${GREEN}$ ${NC}"
```

i.e. changed `\$(get_dir)` to `get_dir`

Result on Cygwin:
[image]

Comment: make sure your bash scripts including `.bashrc` have LF line endings (not CRLF endings).

Answer (score 0):

In your attempt to "fix" it, you execute `get_dir` by the time the `export PS1` is **executed**.

Instead, you need to have it reevaluated  every time a new prompt is generated. The perhaps simplest way to do it is to define a function `my_prompt` which, when called, calculates the PS1 string, and then set

```
export PS1='$(my_prompt)'
```

This also allows you to debug your function before you activate it in the prompt.